# Best way to Store & Access HTML Templates in WEB API C# Application Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, io, asp.net-web-api2

We have Application layer in WEB API application. We are storing HTML email template in one folder of Application layer. Now I want to access that HTML file in my code which is also at same layer. How to access that? Or should I use alternate approach to store & fetch email template ?

```
  string html = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Templates\test.html"));
```

Above line not giving me expected path to access file.

Comment: I either store such things in the database - you can add an api controller to make it accessible to layers above. Or you can store files as embedded resource in an assembly - which can be a dedicated resource assembly for example. But the best solution for you depends on wheter the templates are user editable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below code?

```
ar file = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Templates/test.html");
```